# Apparent contradiction in Feynman's treatment of the velocity distribution of a gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In Feynman's treatment of [statistical mechanics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_40.html), *40–4 The distribution of molecular speeds*, Feynman found that the number of gas molecules per unit area per second who have an upper velocity component $v_{z}$ greater than $u$, $n_{>u}$, is proportional to $ \exp(-\frac{mu^2}{2kT})$, where $m$ is the mass of the molecule.

He then introduces a function $f(u)$,

> let $f(u)du$ be the **fraction** of all the molecules which have velocities between $u$ and $u+du$ ... \begin{equation}
> \label{Eq:I:40:5}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)\,du = 1.
> \end{equation}

Later, he tries to connect $f(u)$ with $ \exp(-\frac{mu^2}{2kT})$, he said,

> First we ask, what is the number of molecules passing through an area per second with a velocity greater than $u$, expressed in terms of $f(u)$? At first we might think it is merely the integral of $\int_{u}^{\infty} f(u)du$, but it is not, because we want the number that are passing the area per second. The faster ones pass more often, so to speak, than the slower ones, and in order to express how many pass, you have to multiply by the velocity. (We discussed that in the previous chapter when we talked about the number of collisions.) In a given time $t$ the total number which pass through the surface is all of those which have been able to arrive at the surface, and the number which arrive come from a distance $ut$. So the number of molecules which arrive is not simply the number which are there, but the **number that are there per unit volume**, multiplied by the distance that they sweep through in racing for the area through which they are supposed to go, and that distance is proportional to $u$. Thus we need the **integral of $u$ times $f(u)du$**, an infinite integral with a lower limit $u$, and this must be the same as we found before, namely $ \exp(-\frac{mu^2}{2kT})$, with a proportionality constant which we will get later:
>   $$\begin{equation}
> \label{Eq:I:40:6}
> \int_u^\infty uf(u)\,du = \text{const}\cdot e^{-mu^2/2kT}.
> \end{equation}$$

So according to the paragraph above $constant\times u$ represents a distance, and $f(u)du$ represents a **density** (number of molecules per unit volume), whereas before it was a **fraction** (unitless) of the total number of molecules. Am I missing something?

N.B. the *const* just above is the same as the proportionality constant between $n_{>u}$ and $ \exp(-\frac{mu^2}{2kT})$.

Comment: That's been absorbed in the "const".

Comment: What has been absorbed in the constant?